# Ошибка LNK2005: ... already defined in ...

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Имеется у меня 3 файла:

- Vector.h
- Vector.cpp
- main.cpp

Я хотел объявить 2 глобальные переменные:

```
 int quantity_copy = 0;
 int quantity_allocates = 0;
```

Объявил их в Vector.h, в двух других файлах пробовал

```
 extern int quantity_copy;
 extern int quantity_allocates;
```

А также подобные различные комбинации различных возможных вариантов, прочел несколько статей на форумах, но тем не менее почему-то постоянно выдает ошибку:

> `Error 6   error LNK2005: "int quantity_copy" (?quantity_copy@@3HA) already defined in main.obj
> Error   7   error LNK2005: "int quantity_allocates" (?quantity_allocates@@3HA) already defined in main.obj
> Error   8   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found`

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, в чем проблема.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Следует различать объявление и определение переменной.

```
extern int a; //объявление
int a; // определение
```

Определение переменной должно встречаться только один раз во всей программе, объявления могут встречаться сколько угодно раз - они подсказывают компилятору, что в каком-то из программных модулей существует определение этой переменной.

В вашем случае переменная определена в заголовочом файле. Может показаться, что определение уникально, но это не так - директива include просто добавляет код подключаемого файла вместо себя, поэтому определен фактически происходит и в main.cpp, и в Vector.cpp. Поэтому правильно сделать так - определение переменной поместить в один из cpp-файлов (например Vector.cpp), а объявление в h-файл (Vector.h).

Comment: Спасибо. "Определение переменной должно встречаться только один раз во всей программе, объявления могут встречаться сколько угодно раз - они подсказывают компилятору, что в каком-то из программных модулей существует определение этой переменной." - так вот представляете - знаю же это, читал, и вроде как понимаю, но как-то не продумал сразу то, о чем вы сказали в след. абзаце, где содержался исчерпывающий ответ. Быть может потому что сидел с 11 дня программировал и вот к 2м ночи закончу. 
p.s.: Можно, если что, вам вопросы задавать по ссылке, указанной в качестве сайта в вашем профиле ?)